# File Attachments timeout and controller method execution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So troubleshooting a weird issue that a client has over slow connections.  The site has a gallery where images can be uploaded and viewed.  The controller that handles the POST first deletes all old images and saves the new images. Some users on slow connections when on job sites POST images it may result in all the images being deleted.

What I believe is happening is because of the slow connection the POSTed images are not making it to the server, but the controller method still executes. The old images are deleted, but since the POST of the images fails the new images are not saved.

Thoughts on how to correct this without creating new pages for specifically adding, changing, deleting images.  Is there a way to detect that the method fired and attachments were expected, but they didnt arrive?

Comment: First, I would probably not delete anything until I confirmed the new items were in place.  Then, if you detect an error, you have not lost data.  As for timeouts, you may want to check out IIS request timeout variable settings in IIS.  Will try and find link

Comment: I dont know if that would help. Basically since no attachments are come over the code assumes all existing images should be deleted.  I agree the implementation isnt the best.  Since the customer doesnt like to spend money I am trying to come up with the least expensive option to fix. So changing the way the image management process is handled is least attractive option.